# Triggering BitBucket Merge from Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, bitbucket

I would like to create the following workflow for Jenkins/BitBucket

```
> User Hits the [Publish] button (custom) within BB PR
> This kicks a Jenkins Pipeline that publishes a previously built .rpm
> If the publish passes, the pipeline triggers BB to merge*
```

[Merge](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.16.0/bitbucket-rest.html?utm_source=%2Fstatic%2Frest%2Fbitbucket-server%2Flatest%2Fbitbucket-rest.html&utm_medium=301#idm8287211200) can be done via this Rest request, but I am not sure how to do this in Groovy yet. I also need to be able to block the [Merge] button. Because merging without publishing the `rpm` will break CI.

Is this a workflow that seems reasonable to implement? If so, is there a way to test the Merge rest request from the Jenkins Script Console to play around?

Comment: SO is no peer review site.  If you have a concrete problem with this, please add the code and the errors you get.  The answer to this might also be higly optinionated since there are no silver bullets.

Comment: @cfrick Will try to get this going further and attempt to update with code snip-its. Because Jenkins seems heavily plugin based, I may need to provide screen shots of setup